# How does a lex file (myscanner.l) works, is it token by token, char by char

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

I would like to see an iteration of the text to scan over the lex file, or the lex.yy.c file in any case.

Answer (score 0):

The lexical scanner reads the input a character at a time, and does something when it recognizes a token. If the user-defined action includes a `return`, then `yylex` returns at that point, otherwise It continues scanning to find the next token (which is also what would happen if `yylex` were called again after the user action returns.)

It is possible that the lexical scanner will have read too far ahead while trying to identify a token, because the token might be the prefix of a longer potential token which turns out not to be matched by the remaining input. In this case, the scanner will reset the scan to the end of the identified token.

If you build the lexical scanner with the `-d` (debug) option and link it with `-lfl`, you should be able to see all of the significant scanner actions in the debugging traces. If that's not sufficient for you needs (or curiosity), I'd suggest using a debugger.